# Python27.dll File Missing - Exception

Tags: python, dll

I have downloaded my code from bit-bucket which was made by my group member. It contain all the frameworks and python script folder. But when I run this code on my system it generates the following error:

> This program can't start because python27.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this program

I have also downloaded and installed python 2.7 on my system but when I run it generates the same error.

Please tell me how can I fix this problem.

Comment: What OS and installation path..?

Comment: My Group Member OS Windows 8.1 (who made the code) My OS Windows 8 Both systems are same i-e 64 Bits. Version on my system 2.7.6 & my group member system is also 2.7.6

Comment: Installation Path is C:/Python 27
My Code is cloned from bitbucket at C:/Folder

Comment: Well that all seems in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most probably a 32-bit or 64-bit issue. Try downloading proper version.

Comment: My Group Member OS Windows 8.1 (who made the code)
My OS Windows 8
Both systems are same i-e 64 Bit

Comment: Did you try fixing the PATH in environment variables?

Answer (score 3):

I also got this error when I copied my python environment from one computer to another. Both computers were 64 bit and the installation was 64 bit. What happens is that python installer updates Microsoft registry. When I simply copied the python files, the registry did not get updated, of course, resulting in the dll file missing error message.

I solved it by installing the 64 bit version of python first on my target computer, and then did my copy of the environment, i.e. copied c:\pythonFromComputerA to target computer's c:\python27, effectively overwriting the python that had just been installed. But because the installer updated the registry, I could now run with my python environment on the target computer without getting the error message.

Thought I'd provide this in case others are out there scratching their heads, having correctly matching installation with OS yet getting this error message.

Comment: Had the same problem. This worked for me. Thank you!