# Python official installer missing python27.dll

Tags: python, windows, dll, installation

I installed Python 2.7 32-bit on Windows from official website and it is missing python27.dll. How can I get this DLL?

Comment: Dont try to add it manually. Try reinstalling or redownloading the installer

Comment: It probably isn't missing, you just didn't look in the right place.

Comment: I searched for python27.dll in installation folder

Comment: It's not in the installation folder. Try googling for your system (32/64 bit *Windows* makes a difference, even for 32 bit Python).

Comment: Using the ActiveState python installer for Windows has always worked for me.

Comment: try http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?python27

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381841/python27-dll-file-missing-exception

Comment: looks like Python distributions put it into installation directory and official Python puts into Windows directory

Answer (score 24, accepted):

At least for the ActiveState Python distribution, and in the official Python distribution:

https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#id7

The dll is in

```
C:\Windows\System\PythonNN.dll
```

where NN is the version number.  On a 64-bit, a 32 bit dll will be installed here:

```
%SystemRoot%\SysWoW64
```

and a running 32 bit application will magically translate this to the proper path, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64

When I link againsy Python27, I use the lib file here:

```
C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib
```

It is somewhat disappointing that the dll gets put in system directories since it means that you can have only one 32 bit and one 64 bit distribution with the same version number.

**Update:**

Note that if you use the Anaconda or Miniconda Python distributions from Continuum Analytics (http://continuum.io), they are much more portable in the sense they package the dll along with the rest of the files in the installation.

Comment: Actually on 64-bit Windows, the 64-bit dll gets installed to `C:\Windows\System32` and not `C:\Windows\System`.

Answer (score 7):

I deploy Python via source control so can't rely on

```
C:\Windows\System\PythonNN.dll
```

To resolve this, I install Python using the msi package and copy the dll into the same directory as the python.exe. I then commit the python folder to source control for our teams to use. Finally, I uninstall Python from my local machine to ensure a clean environment.

I have not noticed an issue with doing this over the past 7 years but would love to learn more about any caveats using this approach.